# Need a delay function within a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Script to send out an email automatically daily.  It is a rather large Google Spreadsheet that has multiple "importrange" functions.  I have a smaller spreadsheet that works perfectly.  However, in the large spreadsheet the data is still loading when the email goes out.  I believe it is because the data does not have time to load before the next function begins.  Does anyone know of a script that can delay the next function within the script before it moves on?  Between the "SheetFlush" and "attachSendPDF" functions.  A copy of the script is below:

```
 function SheetFlush(worksheet) {
worksheet = worksheet || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheets = worksheet.getSheets();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

}

```
function attachSendPDF() { 

  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); 
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  var email = ("Email@gmail.com");
  var subject = "Master Update";
  var body = "Team, here is the Master Update.";
  var todaysDate = new Date();
  var subjectDate = subject+" "+todaysDate


 //this is three level authorization 
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

  //even better code
  //oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("consumerKey"));
  //oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("consumerSecret"));

  var requestData = {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "google",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };

  //"&gid=0&fit to width=true" part is for pdf to b in portrait mode and gid part exports only first sheet . u could have all sheets, so dont put any gid or the number of sheet u wish to export
  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="
      + ssID +  "&exportFormat=pdf&gridlines=true&printtitle=0&size=letter&fzr=true&portrait=0&fitw=true";

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);

  var contents = result.getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subjectDate , body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+todaysDate+".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]}); 

}
`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)
 beware it consumes your daily time quota.